# How to update two fields using counterCache in a table cakephp 2?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to update two fields using counterCache in CakePHP 2.x. I tried this code:

```php
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Table2' => array(
        'className' => 'Table2',
        'counterCache' => 'downvote_count',
        'counterScope' => array('Table2.id' => 0)
    ),
    'Table2' => array(
        'className' => 'Table2',
        'counterCache' => 'upvote_count',
        'counterScope' => array('Table2.id' => 2)
    )
);
```

.. but it only updates last field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Table2' => array(
        'className' => 'Table2',
        'counterCache' => array(
            'downvote_count' => true,
            'upvote_count' => true
        )
    )
);
```